# housekeeper [deleted 105926 hist/trends, 0 items, 0 events, 0 sessions, 0 alarms, 0 audit items in 3.718012 sec, idle for 1 hour(s)]

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

In my zabbix server it logs as

# sudo tail -f /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log

```
housekeeper [deleted 105926 hist/trends, 0 items, 0 events, 0 sessions, 0 alarms, 0 audit items in 3.718012 sec, idle for 1 hour(s)]
```

and after this it fails to send the Alerts

```
5243:20171213:180658.517 Failed sending data to the peer: DATA failed: 550
5243:20171213:180702.182 Failed sending data to the peer: DATA failed: 550
5243:20171213:180705.812 Failed sending data to the peer: DATA failed: 550
```

Can you help me why this occurs and give me a solution

Comment: Those errors are extremely vague, but they resemble SMTP errors - 550 being "mailbox unavailable" or so. If you check Administration -> Audit or Reports -> Action log, are there similar errors reported there?

Comment: Thanks Richlv for your comment . No there were no simalar logs like that i dont know whats happening. i am also bit confused getting this error from past 2 days previously it was fine

Comment: Did you check the action log? There must be failures saved there, which would show you the exact recipients that fail.

Comment: yes Richlv. i get failed actions for all users. thats the wierd thing.

Comment: So your email server is rejecting emails - look in that direction.

Comment: yes thank RIchlv for yor valuble time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this

Beacuase i have configured email to a person in more numbers in the sense

user will get more than 3 alerts for a problem and a ok alert and reduced

the alerts to single alert fro problem per person.

```
when the **zabbix alerter process exceeds 75%** this errors occurs 

    Zabbix alerter processes more than 75% busy
```

and zabbix is not able to send alerts to all peer hosts